# iOS FontAwesome in middle of another string

Tags: ios, nsstring, uilabel, font-awesome

I am trying to display some text and an icon inside a single string using [FontAwesome](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome).

Here is what I have:

```
NSString *icon = [NSString fontAwesomeIconStringForIconIdentifier:@"icon-map-marker"];

NSString *locationString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", icon, otherNormalString];
```

Basically I want to have the map marker show up in front of the location being displayed. Using FontAwesome should make this really simple but I can't quite get it to work right.

Here is also what shows up if I NSLog the string icon:

[image]

Any idea on how I can properly accomplish this?

Comment: Try this.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/34468957/3908884

Answer (score 5):

Strings do not carry any style information (including font). In order to include font information, you'll need to make an `NSAttributedString`. All this `-fontAwesomeIconStringForIconIdentifier` method is doing is returning a unicode value given an identifier.

On the assumption that you're using [ios-fontawesome](https://github.com/alexdrone/ios-fontawesome), you'd want to do something like:

```
... your locationString assignment ...
NSMutableAttributedString *astring = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:locationString];

[astring addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName 
                value:[UIFont iconicFontOfSize:size] 
                range:NSMakeRange(0,1)]; // The first character
```

You can then assign the attributed string to a label's `attributedText` property, or similarly display it.

Comment: This answer is correct, should be flagged as so..
Perhaps you can include a working example so copying/pasting works out of the box.