# How to add font awesome icon in an NSArray in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xib

First I created class name as `NSString+FontAwesome.h` and `NSString+FontAwesome.m` in `NSString+FontAwesome.h`  like following way

```
@import Foundation;
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, FaIcon) {
FaMoonO = 0xf186,
    FaArchive = 0xf187
};

@interface NSString (AwesomeString)

//creates a string with the font awesome character
+(NSString*)awesomeIcon:(FaIcon)index;

@end
```

and in `NSString+FontAwesome.m` code is like this

```
#import "NSString+FontAwesome.h"
@implementation NSString (AwesomeString)

+(NSString*)awesomeIcon:(FaIcon)index
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", (unichar)index];
}

@end
```

I am using code like this for label and it work properly.

```
label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"FontAwesome" size:30];
label.textColor =  [UIColor whiteColor];
label.text =  [NSString awesomeIcon:FaBook];
```

But I want to used it in array any advice.
My array code is like this.

```
iconarray =[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSString awesomeIcon:FaArchive],nil];
```

But it don't show me anything. How can I add `[UIFont fontWithName:@"FontAwesome" size:30]` in an array.
Please help..

Comment: I think you will not see anything, since the icon is tied up with the font you are merely saving a string that will not be readable if the fontAwesome font is not set to the label.

Comment: I also think so, But when I add UIFont it crash. Any suggetion

Comment: maybe you can show us how you add the font? edit it and post some code so we can understand better

Comment: what you want to use it in array? explain clearly..

Comment: I want to use font awesome icon in array. when other array consist its title.

Comment: are you add the FontAwesome.ttf file

Comment: yes. And it work properly in label

Comment: NSMutableAttributedString using to achieve this refer this link https://github.com/alexdrone/ios-fontawesome

Comment: instead of adding the icon to the array add the enum and then read the value, no?

Comment: Show code where you use the array

Comment: iconarray =[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSString awesomeIcon:FaArchive],nil];

Comment: I want to display font awesomeIcon array in table view. Any suggetion

Comment: Please try this for once.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/34468957/3908884

Comment: @Meet Thanks It Work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.h file

```
@import Foundation;
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, FaIcon) {
FaMoonO = 0xf186,
    FaArchive = 0xf187
};

@interface NSString (AwesomeString)

//creates a string with the font awesome character
+(NSString*)awesomeIcon:(FaIcon)index;

@end
```

Used Custom UITableViewCell then in table view used your same code

```
label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"FontAwesome" size:30];
label.textColor =  [UIColor whiteColor];
label.text =  [NSString awesomeIcon:FaBook];
```

for label. Then add that label text in array as

```
iconarray =[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSString awesomeIcon:FaInfo],[NSString awesomeIcon:FaEye],nil];
```